# JSHint not working in vim

Tags: vim, jshint

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed jshint with

```
sudo npm install jshint -g

which jshint
```

shows 
    /usr/local/bin/jshint

Then I added Plug 'https://github.com/walm/jshint.vim.git' in the .vimrc file in ~. I am using vim-plug.

Now, when opening a js-File, such as

```
vim test.js
```

errors are not detected.

```
:JSHint
```

results in "Not an editor command: JSHint"

Earlier pathogen seemed to be working fine with JSHint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `Plug 'https://github.com/walm/jshint.vim.git'` to `Plug 'walm/jshint.vim'`

Run `:PlugInstall`

And test if it the plugin is detected

Comment: this has seemed to fix the earlier problem. But do I need to type :PlugInstall for each time I open a new file with vim??this seems to be the case right now

Comment: Hmm, this seem to me you don't install `vim-plug` properly causing the plugins not to be registered when `Vim` starts. `:PlugInstall` only used when you first install a certain plugin, you don't run it every time you start `Vim`.